# R parallel programming

Tags: r, parallel-processing, package

I have written a simple function tsprob which calculates the sum of all the timestamps of edges of each node and divide the sum with node degree and store it in tsnode vector and tsnode vector is returned atlast. I want to run the function parallely. Can you please suggest me how to rewrite the function using lapply so that I can run the function parallely.

graph is in the form of gml and degree is the vector consists of node degree

```
tsprob <- function(graph,degre)
{
  adj <- get.adjlist(graph)
  tsnode <- matrix(1/degre,1,vcount(graph))
  print(degre)
  i =1
  j=1
  for(i in seq(1:vcount(graph)))
  {
    sum =0
    if(degre[i]>0)
    {
      for(j in seq(1:degre[i]))
      {
        val = adj[[i]][j]
        sum <- sum + E(graph)[i%--%val]$time
      }
      tsnode[i] = sum/degre[i] 
    }
    else tsnode[i] = sum
  }
  return(tsnode)
}
```

Comment: replace for(i) by a lapply: tsnode <- lapply(...)

Comment: If you are not stuck to lapply, it may be easier to rewrite the for loop here with a foreach loop (from package foreach) together with one it's parallelization back-ends like doMC. Are you using Windows?

Comment: No I'm using Ubuntu.. I will try foreach thank you :)